# Using imagemagick in Python3

Tags: python, imagemagick

Is there a python3 module that would let me use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)?

I need the following boarder functions in PythonMagick, which only works in python 2:

```
PythonMagick = Image("image.png")
PythonMagick.borderColor("#ffffff")
PythonMagick.border('1%x1\%')
PythonMagick.write("output.png")
```

Comment: Try [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.5/). I haven't used PythonMagick to compare, but Wand is pretty good.

Comment: @senshin Wands seems to work on python3, it might be what I use, but just spoke to the developer and it does not support passing percentages like in the example code above

Comment: The Python 3 preferred replacement for `%`-based string formatting is [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.forma#str.format), which you should probably look into whether or not you decide to use Wand, since `str.format()` is more powerful.

Comment: @senshin I am not that familiar with python3, but the class in the boarder function is [numbers.Integral](http://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral), its not a string. So its not relevant. Taken from [Wand manual](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/wand/image.html)